# How many grand child Business Units does a child business unit can handle? Is it only limited to 5 BU's?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I want to create a 6th Grand Child business unit in a Child business Unit but what happened is that the 6th Grand Child I created had overlapped the one of the other Grand Child business unit. So, instead of adding a 6th Grand Child business unit it just changed/overlapped one of the 5 Grand Child BU. Does it mean that there is a limit to 5 Grand Child BU in SF Marketing Cloud? Your answers are very much appreciated.

Thanks,
Airvin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be limited in doing what you want, as I have created a number of BU hierarchies with up to a 100 BUs. E.g. a large number of countries as grandchildren, under a B2C child BU: Company Name > B2C > DK,NL,DE,UK,SE,NO,FI,etc

However, you might be facing a contractual limit of BUs. Reach out to your Account Executive at Salesforce to hear, how many BUs are included in the contract - and extend this if necessary.

If you do have enough BUs in contract, but your issue persists, I will advise you to contact support and log a ticket.

Brgds -
Lukas

Comment: Thanks Lukas. 

Is it okay to revert back the BU that I created that overwrites the existing BU? What happened is that there are already 5 existing BU's under the parent BU. What I did is add another BU. When I created the 6th BU, it overwrites the 5th BU name. So, what happened is that the 5th BU was renamed into 6th BU. So, the name 5th BU was missing. How can I revert it back? Does it need to be renamed only? If after renaming it, does it has negative effects on the BU's properties or assets?

Comment: There is no [undo] button. You can just rename the BU, without causing any issues.